# Solaris's implementation cycle processes

Tags: unix, process, solaris

Solaris is a UNIX operating system and assigned me a task currently in college to investigate the implementation of the process cycle in the Solaris operating system.
The problem is that I find anything concrete about it and want any of you share with me a link and give me a clue as to investigate such a broad and scientific as this process. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the OpenSolaris kernel source for starting a process at Illumos.org:  http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/os/main.c#146

Comment: No, the Solaris kernel does NOT use c++. There are too many things that could go badly wrong if the kernel was written in that language.